# Uploading a binary file using fetch

Tags: binary, fetch, zendesk-api

I'm trying to upload a file to Zendesk, here is the API:

```
curl "https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/uploads.json? 
filename=myfile.dat&token={optional_token}" \
-v -u {email_address}:{password} \
-H "Content-Type: application/binary" \
--data-binary @file.dat -X POST
```

This is how my code looks like while file is a `File object` I'm getting from a dropzone:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);

fetch(
  "https://{my-domain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/uploads.json?filename=" + file.name,
  {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
  }
)
```

The problem is that the final file is corrupted because of `WebKitFormBoundary` header and footer.

This is what I tried:

1. Setting `"Content-Type: application/binary"` header as this is what the API expect.
2. Passing the file to the fetch `body` without `FormData` (as-is).
3. Using `FileReader.readAsBinaryString` before passing it to the body.

None of my attempts worked - the server returned error, the only way I was able to create a file is with the `FormData` and without any `Content-Type` header but I didn't find a way to get rid of the `WebKitFormBoundary` header and footer.

For example:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryragq26qGRKa2B9Qg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="README.md"
Content-Type: text/markdown


------WebKitFormBoundaryragq26qGRKa2B9Qg--
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code worked for me:

```
fetch(
  "https://{my-domain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/uploads.json?filename=" + file.name,
  {
   method: "POST",
   body: file,
   headers: {
    "Content-type": file.type
   }
  }
 )
```

Comment: Do image upload work for you? . For me height and width are null on response JSON

Comment: Thanks.. I had to use buffer library to generate binary. Directly uploading base64 string without buffer was getting damged/corrupted at zendesk server